# Windows 11 Doesn't Recognize Password Change

Tags: passwords, windows-11

I changed my Microsoft Account password on my iPhone. I have a Windows 10 PC that runs a hyper-v instance of Windows 11. I'm not sure if the fact I'm running Windows 11 in a VM is related to the issue, but I mentioned it in case it is relevant.

The issue is when I try to connect to the Windows 11 Hyper-V machine it will not accept my new Microsoft Account password, it tells me the password is incorrect. It does work, though, with the previous password. I'm assuming it's cached somewhere, but I'm not sure what to do to clear it or refresh it.

(FWIW, the Windows 10 that is hosting the VM does *not* get logged in with my Microsoft Account.)

Comment: Maybe when you changed the password on your account it logged you off from previous sessions, and the cached version is the previous password. Can you try relogging into your Microsoft Account once you're on the Desktop and see if that solves the issue? Usually I avoid logging in with Microsoft Account on a system-wide configuration, when given the option always choose "Apps only" when logging in, as issues like these can be quite confusing even for someone who has had experience with similar "problems".

Comment: Whether the OS is virtual or physical has no bearing on this - what's likely occurred is the VM was configured with a local account, not an online Microsoft account, else it was configured with a PIN (numerical or alphanumeric).

Comment: @JW0914 - Def. not a local account. Before my password change, it logged in with my Microsoft account password just fine, and that password was not reused anywhere else, such as a local account. And there's no pin set up on the virtual OS, either. I can't even set up a pin.

The fix was to convert it to a local account, then back to using my Microsoft account sign-in. After that, it seems to have recognized the password change.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround than a solution but I was able to get it to recognize the password change by changing my account to a local account and then immediately back to my Microsoft Account.